# Why this code Force Quits?

Tags: java, android

I have starting learning Java and android application development side-by-side. Currently, I a String-array colorsArray which I am trying to print using Log.v

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, defaultActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Challenge</string>
    <string name="red">Red</string>  
    <string name="orange">Orange</string>  
    <string name="yellow">Yellow</string>  
    <string name="green">Green</string>  
    <string name="blue">Blue</string>  
    <string name="indigo">Indigo</string>  
    <string name="violet">Violet</string>  
    <string-array name="colorsArray">  
        <item>@string/red</item>  
        <item>@string/orange</item>  
        <item>@string/yellow</item>  
        <item>@string/green</item>  
        <item>@string/blue</item>  
        <item>@string/indigo</item>  
        <item>@string/violet</item>  
    </string-array>  
</resources>
```

Now I am trying to print that array in different ways, just for practice.

```
package com.gaurish.challenge;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class defaultActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static final String DEBUG_TAG = "PracticeApp";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String aColors[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorsArray);
    printUsingForEach(aColors);
    printUsingWhile(aColors);
    printReverse(aColors);
}

private void printUsingForEach(String[] aColors) {
    for(String i : aColors) {
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "String array printed using for each loop: " + i);
    }
}

private void printUsingWhile(String[] aColors) {
    byte i=0;
    while(i<=aColors.length) {
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "String array printed using While loop: " + aColors[i++]);
    }
}

private void printReverse(String[] aColors) {
    int i=aColors.length -1;
    while(i> (-1) ) {
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "String array printed in reverse order -> " + aColors[i--]);
    }
}
}
```

printUsingForEach() & printUsingWhile() run just fine but printReverse method just not run, the application force quits before reaching. [here is the log](https://gist.github.com/824787) I am building against android 1.6

Please guide this n00b, why this is happening

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Read your log properly, this is an easy error to see an check what line the error is on specifically. defaultActivity.java Line:31

Comment: Sorry, I promise to read logs closely from next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bug in your code:

```
while(i<=aColors.length) { ... }
```

This will cause a loop iteration with `i = aColors.length`, which is out of bounds.

You can see this in your log:

```
02-13 15:24:24.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gaurish.challenge/com.gaurish.challenge.defaultActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
02-13 15:24:24.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
02-13 15:24:24.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at com.gaurish.challenge.defaultActivity.printUsingWhile(defaultActivity.java:31)
```

Comment: Opps, My Bad. I would try harder next time. Thanks for help